# How do I interrupt a div's border with an image?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have three responsively sized divs in a grid that need to have their border-top interrupted by an image. Once I've figured out how to interrupt the top border with an image, I'll do the same thing to the bottom border with a white square. Desired effect is shown in this screenshot: https://ia601903.us.archive.org/20/items/ScreenShot20131007At12.30.32/Practivate-mockup.png

However, the closest I've managed to get so far is this: https://ia601903.us.archive.org/20/items/ScreenShot20131007At12.30.32/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-07%20at%2012.30.32.png

The problem is that absolute positioning breaks the flow of the page, which I could work around if everything was a fixed width, but as it's all responsive (built in Foundation 4) the widths are all unknown. Does anyone know how to do this without absolute positioning?

Here's the code I'm using (inline style only there to make reading it easier on this website, not present in real code):

```
<div class="row" id="about">
    <div class="large-4 columns centered" id="entrepreneurs">
      <div class="thickborder" style="padding-right:10px; padding-left: 10px; margin-top:20px; position:relative">
              <img src="img/white/guitar.png" style="position: absolute; top: -89px;">
      <h2 class="subheader"> For entrepreneurs </h2>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse a venenatis quam, et sagittis quam. Aenean vehicula euismod ipsum, eget blandit libero auctor nec. Aenean pharetra sapien nec risus euismod mattis. Vestibulum volutpat tincidunt blandit. Curabitur dapibus ultrices arcu luctus condimentum. Morbi tellus nisi, accumsan sed hendrerit sit amet, mollis non sapien. Nulla eget purus ut nunc lacinia dignissim. Vestibulum feugiat porta cursus. Curabitur posuere mollis massa quis mollis. Suspendisse ac luctus est, nec vestibulum dolor.</p>
</div></div>


    <div class="large-4 columns centered" id="corporates">
            <div class="thickborder" style="padding-right:10px; padding-left: 10px; margin-top:20px; position:relative">
        <img src="img/white/cloud.png" style="position: absolute; top: -89px">

      <h2 class="subheader"> For corporates </h2>
      <p> consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse a venenatis quam, et sagittis quam. Aenean vehicula euismod ipsum, eget blandit libero auctor nec. Nulla eget purus ut nunc lacinia dignissim. Vestibulum feugiat porta cursus. Curabitur posuere mollis massa quis mollis. Suspendisse ac luctus est, nec vestibulum dolor. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus egestas vestibulum ante egestas adipiscing. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam eros orci, bibendum ut ultricies quis, mollis ut dolor.</p>
</div></div>

    <div class="large-4 columns centered" id="results">
            <div class="thickborder" style="padding-right:10px; padding-left: 10px; margin-top:20px; position:relative">
      <img src="img/white/drinks.png" style="position: absolute; top: -89px">
      <h2 class="subheader"> For results </h2>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse a venenatis quam, et sagittis quam. Aenean vehicula euismod ipsum, eget blandit libero auctor nec. Aenean pharetra sapien nec risus euismod mattis. Vestibulum volutpat tincidunt blandit. Curabitur dapibus ultrices arcu luctus condimentum. Morbi tellus nisi, accumsan sed hendrerit sit amet, mollis non sapien. Nulla eget purus ut nunc lacinia dignissim. Vestibulum feugiat porta cursus. Curabitur posuere mollis massa quis mollis. Suspendisse ac luctus est. </p>
  </div></div>
  </div>
```

Any thoughts much appreciated. This should be a question that's useful to more folks than just me - unless the problem here is that I'm new to this.

Comment: Can you make us a JSFiddle with linked images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential solution is to use negative margins to move the content into the right place.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="column">
    <img class="column-image" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <h2>For entrepeneurs</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc hendrerit vulputate ante ac ornare. Suspendisse quis nisl vitae nisl fringilla imperdiet. Fusce non porta mauris. Pellentesque dapibus lectus ut felis pellentesque facilisis. Aenean condimentum porta aliquet. Duis luctus nisl non metus ornare, id volutpat turpis sodales. Maecenas at augue sed augue auctor laoreet non nec turpis. Suspendisse eu lacinia ligula. Vestibulum est dui, egestas at purus vitae, semper pulvinar leo. Fusce vitae placerat turpis. Mauris dignissim, ipsum ac placerat mollis, nulla mauris dignissim justo, porttitor viverra nisl massa et orci. Donec posuere lectus a orci semper, nec lacinia felis consectetur. Fusce id consequat lectus. Donec sed erat commodo, feugiat ligula vel, posuere augue. Integer id tempor massa.</p>
    <div class="column-footer-fix"></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <img class="column-image" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <h2>For entrepeneurs</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc hendrerit vulputate ante ac ornare. Suspendisse quis nisl vitae nisl fringilla imperdiet. Fusce non porta mauris. Pellentesque dapibus lectus ut felis pellentesque facilisis. Aenean condimentum porta aliquet. Duis luctus nisl non metus ornare, id volutpat turpis sodales. Maecenas at augue sed augue auctor laoreet non nec turpis. Suspendisse eu lacinia ligula. Vestibulum est dui, egestas at purus vitae, semper pulvinar leo. Fusce vitae placerat turpis. Mauris dignissim, ipsum ac placerat mollis, nulla mauris dignissim justo, porttitor viverra nisl massa et orci. Donec posuere lectus a orci semper, nec lacinia felis consectetur. Fusce id consequat lectus. Donec sed erat commodo, feugiat ligula vel, posuere augue. Integer id tempor massa.</p>
    <div class="column-footer-fix"></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <img class="column-image" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
    <h2>For entrepeneurs</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc hendrerit vulputate ante ac ornare. Suspendisse quis nisl vitae nisl fringilla imperdiet. Fusce non porta mauris. Pellentesque dapibus lectus ut felis pellentesque facilisis. Aenean condimentum porta aliquet. Duis luctus nisl non metus ornare, id volutpat turpis sodales. Maecenas at augue sed augue auctor laoreet non nec turpis. Suspendisse eu lacinia ligula. Vestibulum est dui, egestas at purus vitae, semper pulvinar leo. Fusce vitae placerat turpis. Mauris dignissim, ipsum ac placerat mollis, nulla mauris dignissim justo, porttitor viverra nisl massa et orci. Donec posuere lectus a orci semper, nec lacinia felis consectetur. Fusce id consequat lectus. Donec sed erat commodo, feugiat ligula vel, posuere augue. Integer id tempor massa.</p>
    <div class="column-footer-fix"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.column {
    border: 5px solid #06c;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
}

.column-image {
    margin-top: -50px;
}

.column-footer-fix {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/QJSKr/)

A margin is added to the top of the column to make room for the image above it. Using pseudo elements would probably be cleaner using this solution.

The bottom part of the column is kind of hacky, but I don't really have time to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. Why is that inline-block is necessary for the bottom but not the top? Even when using an image for the bottom, it breaks the template if inline-block isn't there, which isn't the case with the top.

Comment: Hmmm, well, it's there because I wanted the `div` element I was using to be centered simply by the `text-align: center` of the parent `.column` element. The `img` at the top did not need one because `img` elements are `inline` by default and are thus affected by `text-align`. As such, it *should* work with an image on the bottom without setting it to `inline-block`. I've created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/QJSKr/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with pseudo elements thus removing the image from the HTML completely.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shkdm/)

```
div.feature-panel
{
    border : solid 10px cornflowerblue;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

div.feature-content
{
    padding : 40px 10px;
    color : cornflowerblue;
    position:relative;
}


.feature-content:before,
.feature-content:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:80%;
    height: 80px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-40%; /* half of width */
    background:white;
}

.feature-content:before {
      top:-45px;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/64/64);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.feature-content:after{
      bottom:-45px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this effect with a negative `margin-top` on the image you want to overlay on your top border and use `margin-left`, `margin-right` as `auto` to center the image in the div.

Here is an example fiddle where I do this http://jsfiddle.net/ndzQP/1/

CSS :

```
div.feature-panel
{
    border : solid 10px cornflowerblue;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

img.feature-image
{
    margin-top : -50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    display : block;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="feature-panel">
<img class="feature-image" src="http://placekitten.com/64/64" />

<div class="feature-content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse a venenatis quam, et sagittis quam. Aenean vehicula euismod ipsum, eget blandit libero auctor nec. Aenean pharetra sapien nec risus euismod mattis. Vestibulum volutpat tincidunt blandit. Curabitur dapibus ultrices arcu luctus condimentum. Morbi tellus nisi, accumsan sed hendrerit sit amet, mollis non sapien. Nulla eget purus ut nunc lacinia dignissim.
</div>
```